# Convert a value(string) to timestamp (Input string has unwanted characters) - SQL

Tags: mysql, hql

I'm trying to convert a value in my table to a timestamp but the value in the table is as below

There's a character 'T' after the date in the string.

### GMT_TIME

20210608T111722.837 GMT

1st Goal:
Achieve the result in the below format

### Output :

GMT_TIME

2021/06/08 11:17:22:837

2nd Goal: Trying to convert it into EST time

### Output

2021/06/08 07:17:22:837

'''
select DATE( DATE_SUB( '1st goal output') , INTERVAL 4 HOUR ) ) from table1
'''

Please give me your valuable input on this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE('20210608T111722.837 GMT', 'T', ''), ' ', 1) AS DATETIME(3))
```

Output: `2021-06-08 11:17:22.837`.

For to convert from GMT to EST use [CONVERT_TZ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function. Remember - you must [import timezones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation) into your server system database for to use mnemonic TZ names (not needed if you use time-formatted offsets).

If you want to substract 4 hours unconditionally then

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE('20210608T111722.837 GMT', 'T', ''), ' ', 1) - INTERVAL 4 HOUR
```

In this case the output datatype will be DATETIME(6), if you need strictly DATETIME(3) then use explicit CAST() additionally.